# Angular 9 - Unclickable button in some specific cases

Tags: angular, typescript, click, visibility

I've got a page with many pieces of information and to make things easier I want to allow the user to show/hide some part when clicking on specific buttons. Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ul-li-hidden-matter?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.scss) of what I did. To summarize the code :

```
 <button [className]="liTrucVisibility" (click)="changeTrucVisibility($event)">part 1</button>
  <div>
    <p>...</p>
  </div>
  <button [className]="liFonctionnalityVisibility" (click)="changeFonctionnalityVisibility($event)">part 2</button>
    <div>
      <h1>another section</h1>
      <p>...</p>
  </div>
```

As you can see, *part1* is always clickable, thus showing and hiding the following `div`. **However** *part2* is **only** clickable if `div` of *part1* is shown.
This is an unexpected behaviour to me and I can't explain why such a thing is happening.

First question: Can someone explain me what's happening ?

Second question: What must be corrected to achieve my goal ?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: i think your `part1` div is overlapping on `part2` button.that's why `part2` button is not clickable. just add a `margin-top` on part2 button for testing and u will see the actual problem.

Comment: Excellent ! This was indeed the matter @FarhatZaman. I thus solved this by using `z-index`. I'll update my stackblitz in case this may be useful to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `position` and `z-index` to set the layers manually. But it might be a overhead if more than 2 layers are involved. Instead you could set the [`visibility`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) property. Try the following

```
button {
    width: 100%;
    color: $darkenedPrimaryColor;
    border: solid 1px $darkenedPrimaryColor;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 0.4rem 8px 0.4rem 8px;
    margin-bottom: 0.6rem;
    &::before {
        margin-right: 1rem;
        margin-left: 1rem;
        content: '\1405';
        color: $darkenedPrimaryColor;
    }
    &.hidden {
        & + div {
            opacity: 0;
            visibility: hidden;
            max-height: 0;
            transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out, max-height 0.2s ease-in-out;
        }
    }
    &.visible {
        &::before {
            content: "\1401";    
        }
        & + div {
            opacity: 1;
            visibility: visible;
            max-height: 100%;
            transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out, max-height 0.2s ease-in-out;
        }
    }
}
```

I've modified your [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ul-li-hidden-matter-fs2rl7)

Comment: Your solution works very well as well, also `z-index`is sometimes a little bit tricky to use (especially if you're not aware that you have to play with `position` parameter). Thank you @MichaelD for your useful answer. I'll keep your solution in mind :-)